# make directory inside html folder in apache server

Tags: php

i am trying to use

mkdir command. i am trying to create a folder under /var/www/html/some-appication . i get permission error.  i need to create a folder in some-application folder . what steps do i need to take before doing it.

here is the command i am using

```
  $structure = '/var/www/html/'.$patientId;
                        if(!is_dir($structure))
                        {
                        if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true))
                         {
                            die('Failed to create folders...');
                         }
                        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to mkdir from a shell? If so, please post the command you are issuing, and the error you receive back.

Comment: no no not from shell...using a php code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly create folder in root directory of a web-server by programming. As you don't have rights to do so. First you need to create folder in root directory & set the proper access rights (777) using FTP. then you can use following syntax for the creation of folder.

`mkdir("/var/www/html/some-appication", 0777)`

no need to use chmod function because it works on setting file permissions not folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Chmod 777 that folder**. You can do that by using **FTP chmod command** or php **chmod** function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: @jedi_coder  
@Bang Dao   please see my code.

since i am trying to create a folder in /var/www/html from code..its problem i guess . bcos owner is root for this naa...how do i get over this?